# How to return true if a word is a so called "token"

Tags: c

So I have an input file that is opened as a read file and is a mad-lib, also a function that copies the mad-lib into an output (write) file. A sample sentence in the input file is "My sister is a very <adjective> person." The token word is the word inside the "<>" so how would I make a Boolean function that returns true if the word is a token? could I use fscanf?

```
FILE* open_file(char prompt[], char mode[]);
bool istoken(char word[]);
void process_file(FILE* in, FILE* out);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE* in = NULL;
    FILE* out = NULL;

    printf("MAD-LIBS Text Processor\n");
    printf("The Program will open a mad-libs file, ask you to fill various words, and produce a funny story.\n");

    in = open_file("Enter mad-lib file name:\n", "r");
    out = open_file("Enter file name for resulting story:\n", "w");
    process_file(in, out);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

/* open_file = prompts user for file name & and attempts to open it, if it fails it prompts the user again. */
FILE* open_file(char prompt [], char mode[]) {
    char filename[255];
    FILE* in;

    do {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        scanf("%s", filename);

        in = fopen(filename, mode);

        if (in == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to open file: %s. Try Again!\n", filename);
        }
    } while(in == NULL);
    return in;
}
/* process_file = processes entire input file and writes it to output file */
void process_file(FILE* in, FILE* out) {
    char content[MAX_LEN];

    while(fgets(content, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL) {
        fprintf(out, "%s", content);
    }
}
/* istoken = returns true if word is a token */
bool istoken(char word[]) {                 //USE FSCANF MAYBE
    char target = '<';



    return true;
}
```

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Unless there's a clear distinction between sentences/lines/where you expect to find tokens, I'd just read the entire file into a buffer, then scan it character by character looking for `'<'` and `'>'` and gathering the word in between. I don't think parsing it word by word and passing those words to a `bool istoken(...)` function buys you much.

Comment: It is set up to where I must do it that way. yano

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question that you asked:

```
#include <string.h>

...

bool istoken(char word[])
{
  return (word[0]=='<' && word[strlen(word)-1]=='>');
}
```

Of course this entirely depends on passing in a properly `NUL` terminated string.  If you're passing a pointer to somewhere in the middle of a buffer:

```
bool istoken(char word[], size_t wordLength)
{
  return (word[0]=='<' && word[wordLength-1]=='>')
}
```

You'll have some word-parsing work to do before you call either of these functions, however.

Comment: how do I know if that function is working then? Yano

Comment: @StacyWillis It will return `true` for any word that begins with `'<'` and ends with `'>'`, `false` otherwise